# php: unable to iterate for each loop

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

I am facing the follow error from the below code:

Error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Code:

```
 //--------This is the code for jquery UI autocompleter-------------

include "inc/connect.php";
$skeyword = $_GET["term"];
$req = "SELECT  p.prm_title ,a.am_name, c.cm_name ,l.lm_name ,b.bm_name,r.pm_name  "
    . "FROM product_master p,author_master a,category_master c,language_master l,binding_master b ,publisher_master r "
    . "WHERE p.prm_title LIKE '%$skeyword%' OR a.am_name LIKE '%$skeyword%'
       OR c.cm_name LIKE '%$skeyword%' OR l.lm_name LIKE '%$skeyword%' OR b.bm_name LIKE '%$skeyword%' OR r.pm_name LIKE '%$skeyword%'  
       GROUP BY p.prm_id LIMIT 10";

$res = mysql_query($req);
$ret = array();
foreach (mysql_fetch_array($res) as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $val) //--Error: from this line, Why?
    {
        if (false !== stripos($val, $skeyword)) {
            $ret[] = $val;
            break;
        }
    }
}

$testme = json_encode($ret);
echo $testme;
```

The above code is written for jquery auto-completer to search in many column field, but it will return only the matched column.

Please help me to solve this issue..

Comment: Change your first foreach into a while loop. See the `mysql_fetch_array` [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## why:

If a variable:

- is not `array`
- does not implements the interface `Iterator`

and it is used to iterator by `foreach`, this error will raise.

---

## How to fix

`mysql_fetch_array` returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or `FALSE` if there are no more rows, so use a `while` loop to fetch result:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    // if $row is false, the code will not hit here.
    foreach ($row as $val)
    {
        if (FALSE !== stripos($val, $skeyword))
        {
            $ret[] = $val;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

## update:

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        // if $row is false, the code will not hit here.
        foreach ($row as $val)
        {
            if (FALSE !== stripos($val, $skeyword) && !in_array($val, $ret))
            {
                $ret[] = $val;
                break;  // what this break for?
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: As I know, it won't. Would you paste the output in your question?

Comment: Yes its repeating, i searched a keyword `ravi` as author name, then i got output like `["Ravi Belagere","Ravi Belagere","Ravi Belagere","Ravi Belagere","Ravi Belagere","Ravi Belagere","Ravi Belagere","Ravi Belagere","Ravi Belagere","Ravi Belagere"]`    Its returning all the book table row where this author belongs to

Comment: OK, If you only want to get `one record`, try the code in my update.

Comment: sorry, u did not understand my exact problem. The new update u shown above is not correct for multiple data match. I WANT ONLY 1 RESULT FOR THE `SAME` MATCHED KEYWORD.  example:   value `hello` & `hello` are same so they should appear only once, but if i have values like `hello` & `hello9` then the both should appear.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.
Use `while` instead of `foreach`

```
//--------This is the code for jquery UI autocompleter-------------

include "inc/connect.php";
$skeyword = $_GET["term"]; 
$req = "SELECT  p.prm_title ,a.am_name, c.cm_name ,l.lm_name ,b.bm_name,r.pm_name  "
        . "FROM product_master p,author_master a,category_master c,language_master l,binding_master b ,publisher_master r "
        . "WHERE p.prm_title LIKE '%$skeyword%' OR a.am_name LIKE '%$skeyword%'
                      OR c.cm_name LIKE '%$skeyword%' OR l.lm_name LIKE '%$skeyword%' OR b.bm_name LIKE '%$skeyword%' OR r.pm_name LIKE '%$skeyword%'  
                      GROUP BY p.prm_id LIMIT 10";

    $res = mysql_query($req);
            $ret = array();
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                foreach ($row as $val)   //--Error: from this line, Why?
                {
                    if (FALSE !== stripos($val, $skeyword))
                    {
                        $ret[] = $val;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } 

$testme = json_encode($ret);
echo $testme;
```

Comment: Why i can not use for each loop ...why it works when i kept `while` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Again, but now as an answer:

Change your first foreach into a while loop. See the `mysql_fetch_array` [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Answer (score 0):

Please **always** verify that the parameter for the "foreach" is an array.
Your SQL request may return FALSE if there is no row matching your conditions, and foreach on FALSE does not work :)

So after your code

```
foreach (mysql_fetch_array($res) as $row)
```

You have to verify that $row is an array and not false before trying to iterate over it.

```
if (is_array($row))
```

Or you may be more explicit and use mysql_num_rows, which tells you if the query returns some rows or not :

```
if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) 
{
    $ret = array();
    foreach ( mysql_fetch_array($res) as $row)
    // ...
}
```

But the right solution, as exposed above by djot and Amol, is to use the

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
```

which ensure that if $row is FALSE, then you won't enter the block and you won't try to iterate on FALSE.